# Newton Rhapson Algorithm Accuracy

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, recurrence-relations

I read somewhere that the NR algorithm in general (given an appropriate initial value) increases in accuracy by roughly two decimal places per iteration.

Is this something that can be proven, or is it just a general rule of thumb that happens to work for a large number of functions?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method

Comment: It is (after a while) usually much better than that. The number of correct decimal places roughly doubles, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32. When she is good, she is very very good.

Comment: Until you run into machine precision and roundoff errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_k$ be the $x$ at the $k$ iteration, and $\alpha$ be the root we are looking for.

After applying taylor's formula + Lagrange remainder:

$f(\alpha)=f(x_k)+(\alpha-x_k)f'(x_k)+\frac{1}{2}(\alpha-x_k)^2f''(\beta)$

Since $alpha$ is a root, $f(\alpha)$ is zero

$f(x_k)+(\alpha-x_k)f'(x_k)+\frac{1}{2}(\alpha-x_k)^2f''(\beta)=0$

We can divide by $f'(x_k)$ to simplify things a bit:

$$\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}+(\alpha-x_k)+\frac{(\alpha-x_k)^2f''(\beta)}{2f'(x_k)}=0$$

Since $x_{k+1}=x_k-\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}$, $\frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}=x_k-x_{k+1}$

So we will rewrite the previous term:

$$x_k-x_{k+1}+(\alpha-x_k)+\frac{(\alpha-x_k)^2f''(\beta)}{2f'(x_k)}=\alpha-x_{k+1}+\frac{(\alpha-x_k)^2f''(\beta)}{2f'(x_k)}=0$$

So...

$$x_{k+1}-\alpha=\frac{(\alpha-x_k)^2f''(\beta)}{2f'(x_k)}$$

Add absolute value to get error term:

$$|x_{k+1}-\alpha|=|\frac{(\alpha-x_k)^2f''(\beta)}{2f'(x_k)}|$$

$f''(\beta)$ is just a number, a scalar if you will, we assume that $f'(x_k)$ is not zero (if it is, then the process could fail and we aren't assured convergence). So this is a function of $(\alpha-x_k)^2$ which proves quadratic convergence.

This basically means that every iteration you are DOUBLING the number of precision digits. When it converges, it is very very good, the problem is, that unless certain restrictions apply, we can't be assured of convergence. Thankfully, those restrictions are not too strict.

Generally speaking, if you can find a neighborhood $[a,b]$ such that $\alpha \in [a,b]$, and also $f'(x)$ is not zero in $[a,b]$ and also $f''$ is bounded on $[a,b]$, any $x_0 \in [a,b]$ that you choose will converge (assuming $[a,b]$ is not too large).

Comment: Thanks for your response, very helpful. However, in your first line where you used Taylor's Formula + Lagrange Remainder, why did you stop at the second order term? How come you didn't continue with the third derivative, fourth etc?

Comment: @Trogdor I stopped at the second order term because I assume $x_0$ is sufficiently close to the root ($[a,b]$ is small enough) such that we can ignore higher order terms. Also see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html for more information.

Comment: I just realised that the proof you provided relies on the fact that $\alpha-x_k$ differ by less than 1, to guarantee that when we compute $(\alpha-x_k)^2$, the precision digits double.

How would this work then if $x_k$ is chosen to be say 1.5 units away from $\alpha$? Squaring it would increase the margin of error!

Comment: Newton-Raphson method does not always converge. If it converges, then at a certain point, $|x_k-\alpha|<1$ will be correct. If you are looking for a formula that will tell you how fast it converges start to finish, then to my knowledge, no such formula exists, since newton-raphson behaves erratically and does not work for all function. One of the downsides of newton-raphson as you noticed, is that the region we work in $[a,b]$ has to be sufficiently small.